# using gcp billing export to understand usage in cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use bigquery usage export to understand how much data we have in GCS but I'm not sure my query is correct as the number of gigabytes its showing is much lower than what I have in Cloud Metrics..

for example, if I run this query:

```
select name, month, sum(used_storage) as used_storage
from (
  SELECT project.name, sku.description, invoice.month, max(usage.amount_in_pricing_units) as used_storage
  FROM `mybilling_table` 
  WHERE service.description = "Cloud Storage" and sku.description in (
    "Standard Storage US Multi-region",
  "Standard Storage Northern Virginia",
  "Nearline Storage Northern Virginia",
  "Standard Storage US Regional",
  "Coldline Storage Northern Virginia",
  "Nearline Storage US Multi-region",
  "Coldline Storage US Multi-region",
  "Archive Storage US Multi-region",
  "Standard Storage Europe Multi-region",
  "Archive Storage Northern Virginia"
  )
  and project.name = 'my-project'
  and invoice.month = '202211'
  group by 1,2,3

  order by invoice.month desc
)
group by 1,2
order by 1,2 desc
```

I get this back:

```
name            month   used_storage
my-project      202211  10876.467154139504
```

which I believe is 10,876 gigabytes.

but when I look at cloud metrics to see how much data we have in GCS for that project I get 309tb (see screenshot)... what am I missing in my query[image]?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out... need to change `max(usage.amount_in_pricing_units)` to  `sum(usage.amount_in_pricing_units)`... working now!